# How to get text between div tags with id being 1st attribute. Only with regular expressions.

Tags: php, html

Here is the scenario

I'm using this regular expression for getting the text inside div tag with id test

```
<div id = "test">text</div>

$regex = "#\<div id=\"test\"\>(.+?)\<\/div\>#s";
```

My only requirement is to get the text from div tags in below scenario

```
<div id="test" class="teating" style="color:red" etc etc .... more attributes >
```

i.e id being the 1st attribute of div tag and can be followed by n number of attributes.
How to extract text from such a tag by regex only. Please help 
Thanks You.

Comment: You can't parse HTML with regular expressions because HTML is not a regular language. [Here's why](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this regex :

```
$regex = '#<div\s+.*?id="test".*?>(.*?)</\s*div>#ims';
```

Comment: [You can't parse HTML with regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not)

Comment: He is already using regular expressions, he only needs to adapt it, so I answered his question, no more no less, (but his html is surely in a variable).

Comment: Don't substitute one wrong solution for another, Yazmat. You're better than that.

Comment: Hey i checked it but didn't worked is there any thing left out ....
Can you please confirm

Answer (score 0):

in php:
with $replacement defined as your input string.

```php
$pattern = '#<div[^/>]*>([^<]*)</div>#';
$replacement = '\1';
$text = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $subject);
```