# How to get text between div tags with id being 1st attribute followed by multiple attributes. Only with regular expressions

Tags: php, html, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get text between div tags with id being 1st attribute. Only with regular expressions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11780553/how-to-get-text-between-div-tags-with-id-being-1st-attribute-only-with-regular)

Here is the scenario

I'm using this regular expression for getting the text inside div tag with id test1,or tes2 or test3

```
<div id = "test1">text</div>
<div id = "test2">text</div>
<div id = "test3">text</div>

$id_value = "test1" or "test2" or "test3";
$regex = "#\<div id=\"".$id_value."\"\>(.+?)\<\/div\>#s";
```

My only requirement is to get the text from div tags in below scenario

```
<div id="test" class="testing" style="color:red" etc etc .... more attributes >text</div>
```

i.e id being the 1st attribute of div tag and can be followed by n number of attributes. How to extract text from such a tag by regex only.

I even tried

```
$regex = '#<div\s+.*?id="".$id_value."".*?>(.*?)</\s*div>#ims';
```

it is returning text of div tag when $id_value = "test1" but if $id_value="test2" it is returning text values of both nodes test1 and test2. If $id_value="test3" it is returning text value of all 3 nodes. I need text value related to specific id only. **Using Regex only.**

Please help Thanks You.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please refrain from parsing HTML with RegEx as it will [drive you į̷̷͚̤̤̖̱̦͍͗̒̈̅̄̎n̨͖͓̹͍͎͔͈̝̲͐ͪ͛̃̄͛ṣ̷̵̞̦ͤ̅̉̋ͪ͑͛ͥ͜a̷̘͖̮͔͎͛̇̏̒͆̆͘n͇͔̤̼͙̩͖̭ͤ͋̉͌͟eͥ͒͆ͧͨ̽͞҉̹͍̳̻͢](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Use an [HTML parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php) instead.

Comment: i know man but this case i need to use regex only :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use RegExp to parse HTML. Instead, use PHP's **[DOM extension](http://php.net/dom)** which can correctly parse any kind of HTML.

Example:

```
<?php

    $html = <<<HTML
<div id = "test1">text</div>
<div id = "test2">other text</div>
<div id = "test3">new text</div>
HTML;

    $id_list = array(
        "test1",
        "test2",
        "test3",
    );

    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($html);
    foreach ($id_list as $id) {
        $div = $doc->getElementById($id);
        if ($div == NULL) {
            echo "There's no element with an ID of $id<br>\n";
        }
        else {
            echo "$id's content is: " . $div->textContent . "<br>\n";
        }
    }
```

If and only if you absolutely must use RegExp, this is what I came up with:

```
<?php

    $html = <<<HTML
<div id = "test1">text</div>
<div id = "test2">other text</div>
<div id = "test3">new text</div>
HTML;

    $id_list = array(
        "test1",
        "test2",
        "test3",
    );

    foreach ($id_list as $id) {
        $pattern = <<<REGEX
/
<div\s*                     #Opening Tag
(?:                         #Attributes before ID
    [a-z]+                  #Attribute name
    \s*=\s*                 #Equals
    (?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*')     #Attribute content
    \s*                     #Spaces?
)*                          #Many or none
(?:                         #ID Attribute
    id
    \s*=\s*
    (?:"$id"|'$id')         #Matches the ID
    \s*
)
[^>]*                       #Anything after ID
>                           #Closing Tag
([^<]*)                     #Actual content!
<\/div>
/xi
REGEX;

        preg_match_all($pattern, $html, $matches);
        var_dump($matches);
    }
```

Beware, if you use this code, the unh̶oly͘ ͘c̀h̶i͏l҉d wį
ll weep the blood of virgins. The `<cent`er> cannot hold it is too late.

Comment: I need to do it by Regex Only no option left can you help in that way ??? :)

Comment: @JanmajayAdhikari: I'm sure it's possible, but why would you give yourself such a major headache?

Comment: Ya I know but m project architecture is not allowing me to use DOM parser that's the only reason....... why would i make things tough for me :( ............. can you help me regarding regex ???

Comment: @JanmajayAdhikari: I will try to set up an example :)

Comment: I'll try it out ....... I'm out of office now...... will inform you whether it worked for me or not ........... Thanks a lot for the help :)

Comment: There's a reason people say not to parse HTML with RegEx. It isn't a programmer's joke, it isn't something you can say "I know, but I have to". No. No. No. No. No.  You don't "have to". There's no reason, NONE, that you *have* to parse RegEx with HTML. That's like **having** to hammer nails with a wet noodle. It is an unreasonable requirement. An impossible requirement. Fly to the moon, right now, no pants. Singlehandedly reverse global warming using only flamethrowers. Solve for 1/0. No. Just... no. Your requirement is a lie.

Comment: hey truth copy pasted the same thing not working i think some problem with regex

Comment: @JanmajayAdhikari: It works as is for me. What problems are you having?

Comment: Sorry to bother you Truth I miss typed something ............. 
Thanks a lot for helping :)

Comment: @JanmajayAdhikari: If the answer did solve your problem, consider accepting it by click on the large green tick mark under the answer's score.

Comment: @bandwaggon, though quite late to join, kindly note that PHP DOMDocument's `textContent` will strip all html tags before returning a value. Hence it will display only pure text content.

Comment: @AbhishekMadhani: That's correct. Although OP gave a pretty specific requirement that does not include HTML inside the `div`..

Comment: @MadaraUchiha, absolutely your answer is spot on. Just a suggestion for other people who might be coming from Google Search while searching for related question. As I came across.